# GoneToNajIsSquat

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

There is a riddle whose answer is one word only. My friend, who loves puzzles, gave this to me.

**Riddle:** GoneToNajIsSquatAndSmellLetsTryShellSomeZooAJockShisSunThatSangAHlnt

My guess: If you combine all the capital letters, you get: GTNISASLTSSZAJSSTSAH

But I don't know how to find one word answer form it. Is it anagram or what?

Comment: Um what? I think we need to open this conversation.