Atbash Decipher Puzzle
I got this puzzle from a friend who usually participates in online/offline puzzle competitions. He has a complex mindset and very strict discipline. I think the answer is a word.

gmrsztmzhgzsgmfhhrsgpxlpzllavnlhoovshbighgvooovnhwmzgzfjhhrkzmlgvmlt


Hint 1: If you’re caught between a Gnoll and Mountain, stay strong and unwavering. That's the only way to stay on the righteous path.
Hint 2: Is it four. Don't forget your self at door.
Hint 3: When you enter a room, the door is what on your  journey.

Now, I reversed entire string (which he confirmed is correct) and then I deciphered with atbash (which he didn't confirm) and found this after deciphering:

gonetonapissquatandsmellletstryshellsomezooakockthissunthatsangahint

He mainly now said to focus on Hint 2.
I am not sure what are the next step to find the final answer.

Oh yeah..Cryptic-Clue tag removed.
He usually participate in online/offline puzzle competitions. Has some complex mindset. Have very strict discipline.

I got a slightly different string than you. I got GoneToNajIsSquatAndSmellLetsTryShellSomeZOOAJOakShisSunThatSangAHlnt

@DanDan面Sorry for that. 3-4 letters were wrong. Now corrected.
Here is correct one: gmoSZtmzHgzsGmfHhrsHpxlQZllAvnlHoovsHbiGhgvOoovnHwmZgzfjHhRqzMlGvmlT

Thanks. Can you verify the original cipher actually starts with gmoS? In particular that the 3rd character is an o.

@DanDan面 Yes, third character is o and it starts with gmoS

@DanDan面 Puzzle updated. Please check

Is this a semi-duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/126078 ?
